# How do I export a combine gif as a replace gif?

Tags: image, animation, render, gif

So I have a gif, and it uses the combine method. I want to render all the frames and export them, preferably as another gif. How do I do this?

Comment: this question belongs to [**http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @freestock.tk yeah I couldn't remember what it was called